# log4net - enhance to automatically include another field in each row

Tags: c#, logging, optimization

I have written an application which logs multiple entries using log4net. I have several hundreds of calls in Log.Error, Log.Info, Log.Debug, and their corresponding format methods.

In my config file I have the following format entry:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Each class has on top the following:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ClassName));
```

And every single instance of each class that uses the logger also has a field named "id".

Is there a way to leave each entry as it is i.e.:
Log.InfoFormat("Received event for user {0}", user);
which should print:

> 2018-07-03 10:17:42,030 [28] DEBUG MyApplication.ClassName - Received
>   event for user .....

But enhance it to print this instead:

> 2018-07-03 10:17:42,030 [28] DEBUG MyApplication.ClassName - **ID = 1**
>   Received event for user .....

A way to deal with it would be to create a LoggerWrapper, which would be constructed in every single class. The LoggerWrapper should provide all methods already provided by the Logger and should delegate to the encapsulated Logger with the id appended in every message as well. Its constructor would get the id of each element.

Then I should go to every single call to the logger and replace it with a call to the LoggerWrapper instead. Is there any other way to do it with fewer changes?

Comment: Why not simply append the ID into to Log.InfoFormat command?

Comment: @Wheels73 As I said, I have several hundreds of entries and did not want to go at every single one of them and append the id.

Comment: I mis-read that bit sorry. If it were me, I would simply do CTRL + SHIFT + H and do a solution wide replace, assuming the ID is held in the same accessible var in each class. Definitely quicker than adding a wrapper and making the classes call the wrapper.

Comment: @Wheels73 ok, thanks. Since I do not think there is an other way, I might do it like this.